# rx.Scheduler cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin, dagger-2, rx-android

I do have two custom annotations

```
@Qualifier
@kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class IOScheduler
```

and

```
@Qualifier
@kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class UIScheduler
```

I'm using them in my module

```
@Module
class UiModule {

    @Provides
    @UIScheduler
    fun provideUiScheduler(): Scheduler = AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()

    @Provides
    @IOScheduler
    fun provideIOScheduler(): Scheduler = Schedulers.io()

}
```

Of course module is added to my component, and when i'm trying to inject them it says

> rx.Scheduler cannot be provided without an @Provides- or
>   @Produces-annotated method.

injecting

```
class MainPresenter(val view: MainContract.View) : MainContract.Presenter {

    @Inject lateinit var api: ApiServices
    @Inject lateinit var databaseManager: DatabaseManager
    @Inject @UIScheduler lateinit var observeScheduler: Scheduler
    @Inject @IOScheduler lateinit var subscribeScheduler: Scheduler
  ...
}
```

Funny think is that i'm using almost same think with injecting Gson for my ApiClient and it works perfectly

```
@Module
class ApiModule {

...

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @DefaultGson
    fun providesGson(): Gson = GsonBuilder().create()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @FormatDateGson
    fun providesGsonFormatTimestamp(): Gson = GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(Constants.TIME_STAMP_FORMAT).create()
}

@Singleton
class ApiClient @Inject constructor(@DefaultGson val gson: Gson, val sharedPreferences: SharedPrefsUtils) {
   ...
}
```

In additional i can say that i do have same modules / providers structure in my java projects and it works just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use custom annotations with `field:` target e.g.

```
@Inject @field:IOScheduler lateinit var subscribeScheduler: Scheduler
```

---

**In other news**: Dagger refuses to do the following:

```
@Inject internal  var something: Boolean  = false // or
@Inject protected var toolbar:   Toolbar? = null
```

The error looks like this:

> Dagger does not support injection into private fields

This affects any variables without the `lateinit` modifier.

<s>You'll have to expose primitives in your component and inject them manually.</s>

Just specify the `set:` target so injection is done via public/internal/protected setter instead of the private backing field like this:

```
@set:Inject internal  var something: Boolean  = false // or
@set:Inject protected var toolbar:   Toolbar? = null
```

---

**Custom annotations**

Declare your custom annotations with

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD, AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER, AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER)
```

-- pretty much anything except `PROPERTY` because that is invisible to Java. The compiler will now show an error if you try to use an annotation without `get:`, `set:` or `field:` target. And you need that target so the annotation takes effect.